# Reroute Python Module To Another Directory (Sub-version) on import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, compatibility

```
mypkg/
├── mypkg-1_0_0/
│   ├── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
```

The above directory is an example of what my modules directory looks like. The master module `mypkg` contains all the sub-versions. When I do `import mypkg` the `__init__` file is meant to redirect the import to the correct version while running the target versions `__init__` file and also setting the attributes to `globals()`

Here is what the `__init__.py` in `mypkg` looks like:

```
def __load():
    import os

    pkgrelease = "mypkg-1_0_0"

    if pkgrelease:
        current_path = __path__[0]

        new_path = os.path.join( current_path, pkgrelease )
        init_path = os.path.join( new_path, "__init__.py" )

        __path__[:] = [new_path]

        initf = open( init_path )
        exec compile( initf.read(), init_path, "exec" ) in globals()
        initf.close()

    else:
        raise ImportError( "Could not find [%s] package version" % os.path.basename(__path__) )

__load()

del __load
```

In `python2` this works fine, the package gets redirected to version `1_0_0`, and stuff like `__version__` in that versions `__init__` file, are retained and set in the `globals()`. But I also know there is a much better way to do what I'm trying to achieve here that is cross-compatible. This will not work in python3 due the exec compile statement.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this other `__init__`? If you wanted to import it, how would you do it?

Comment: There are much better ways of doing this. Even in python2

Comment: When is the decision made to which implementation is loaded when you do import mypkg?

Comment: This is called an xy problem: you think you need to port an exec statement, but really you need help fixing the code smell it represents.

Comment: Please post a sample directory structure, what your user import looks like, and what you want to actually import. Your current code is an example of how you acheive the redirect now. You're looking for a more portable way to do the redirection, not necessarily to port that exact code.

Comment: Yes, rewrite the question entirety. Ping me when you're done. I'd also recommend deleting the question until you're done. It's trivial to undelete, and will prevent people from posting low quality answers in the meantime.

Comment: The test `if pkgrelease:` is not very useful. Also, don't start names with double underscores in py3. It causes problems if you're not careful. You gain nothing in this case anyway since you delete the load function

Comment: Does the nested package ever contain other modules? Do you care what the `__module__` attributes of the functions and classes in your module are? Do you care about sub-packages?

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips. I will have other modules in the target package. Ideally I'd like to keep `__module__` attrs pointing to the master pkg.

Comment: Not sure what  you mean by sub-packages but the `mypkg-1_0_0` should behave just like any other python module. So this means it will have python files in it, and directories in it as  well. *Deleting comments for cleanup*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm going to think about this. It's a very good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution that works on both py2/3. Simply just need to tweak the `exec` function to take in the `globals()` an argument. This is shown [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). Here is the revised code:

```
def load():
    import os

    pkgrelease = "mypkg-1_0_0"

    current_path = __path__[0]

    new_path = os.path.join( current_path, pkgrelease )
    init_path = os.path.join( new_path, "__init__.py" )

    __path__[:] = [new_path]
    initf = open(init_path)
    module = compile(initf.read(), init_path, "exec")
    exec(module, globals())
    initf.close()


load()

del load
```